# Navigation stack not going straight

Tags: ros, navigation, odroid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I previously posted about my robot rotating in place but that has been solved as it is due to the map not being aligned.

However, the robot now turns left and right towards the set goal instead of going straight.

Have taken advice on previous post to tweak parameters like `base_local_planner_params.yaml` and both local and global costmap param but issue persist. Is there any possible solution to this and please let me know what information would be informative and I will update ASAP.
Thank you.

Info:

- followed: https://automaticaddison.com/how-to-set-up-the-ros-navigation-stack-on-a-robot/ (have went through his tutorial prior to this link as well and there are no issue)
- SBC- Odroid C4
- RPLiDAR a1m8
- MCU - Arduino Uno
- motor driver l298n
- bno055 imu sensor
- pololu magnetic quad encoder

**Github**: https://github.com/roomtempiq/Odroid_bot

Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398779/navigation-stack-not-going-straight/) by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2022-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on 2022-04-10**:
I have added my github repository for this project as suggested by another user.

**Comment by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on 2022-04-11**:
The robot when met with an obstacle, it is unable to change its trajectory and rotate in place. This eventually leads to the map and laser scan misaligned. Is this possibly still base_loacal_planner (for not going straight and unable to change planned path with obstacle) and amcl (laser scan) issue?

Any help even a comment on possible issue is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

**Comment by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on 2022-04-11**:
will replacing base local planner with dwa planner work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> However, the robot now turns left and
> right towards the set goal instead of
> going straight.

I look into your code and it looks like you have some `code smells` there, e.g.

```
// Check if we need to turn 
  if (cmdVel.angular.z != 0.0) {
 
    // Turn left
    if (cmdVel.angular.z > 0.0) {
      pwmLeftReq = -PWM_TURN;
      pwmRightReq = PWM_TURN;
    }
    // Turn right    
    else {
      pwmLeftReq = PWM_TURN;
      pwmRightReq = -PWM_TURN;
    }
  }
  // Go straight
  else {...}
```

You are checking `cmdVel.angular.z != 0.0`, when checking `cmdVel.angular.z < SOME_MIN_DIFF` would be better for uC.
I am not so sure with your PWM control too - did you check it on the real robot?

```
// Publish tick counts to topics
leftPub.publish( &left_wheel_tick_count );
rightPub.publish( &right_wheel_tick_count );
```

Are these for sure synchronized? Your comment with

> However, the robot now turns left and
> right towards the set goal instead of
> going straight.

seems to be connected to this.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on 2022-04-14**:
I recalculated my ticks per meter, k_p and b constant. and it now goes left & right and straight then repeat towards the goal.
Seems that it is an improvement and that the issue is contributed by the diff drive controller.
I will look into what u have mentioned above and also use my new parameters and configure the base_local planner
Thank you

**Comment by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on 2022-04-15**:
Left and right wheel ticks are in sync and have negligible difference when checking with rostopic echo /.
If thats what u meant by synchronized. Let me know if I am mistaken and also so, what is uC?
Thank you very much

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-15**:
uC - microcontrollers, but I thought about hardware overall here. In reality you will never have a "pure" zero in something, it will be nearly always some 10e-7 value etc. Usually it is solved by a kind of dead zone around boundary values, e.g. `abs(cmdVel.angular.z) <  0.001` should be treated as a zero. Right now I think about the frequency of your cmd_vel commands, maybe they are published less frequently than they should? How is your driver working with rapid changing of PWM values?

**Comment by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on 2022-04-16**:
oh I see "u" as in micro. Will try to give an allowance for `abs(cmdVel.angular.z)`.
I used `rqt_robot_steering rqt_robot_steering` and publish different speed to the robot and it does react instantaneously.
Will be updating later if I have better result with what I have done.
Once again, thank you.

**Comment by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on 2022-04-16**:
Hello, I changed the map update and publish frequency to 60 instead of 30, changed to `abs(cmdVel.angular.z) < 0.001` instead of `<0.0` and it work towards the goal without rotation with a static obstacle!

So I tried to find out if it's the map parameter or the angular allowance that made this improvement by:

1. changing the angular back to '<0.0' with updated map param
2. changing map param to 30hz with updated `abs(cmdVel.angular.z) < 0.001`

Changing `abs(cmdVel.angular.z) < 0.001` back to zero shows the rotation problem. But updating it back to `abs(cmdVel.angular.z) < 0.001` does not replicate the first time I did it.
Why is this happening?
**Update**: I further tried with a smaller value of 0.0001 and 0.00001. It remains the same. I guess i made a mistake? I should increase the value correct?

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-16**:
I am not sure what are you asking here, to be honest, with replicating things etc. With values - you know for sure from school inequalities with a module, e.g. |x| < 0.1 or |x| < 0.01 - the first one has a bigger range of solutions: (-0.1; 0.1), second one smaller: (-0.01;0.01). If you increase RHS of this inequality you will get bigger "dead zone" around zero - this way your code is more robust to small differences, e.g. controller will wait for bigger differences to change it's control. Smaller RHS - more sensitive control.

**Comment by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on 2022-04-17**:
Yes I understand what you mentioned. I overlook things as I was constantly trying and my brain kind of died.
What I meant by replicating is that I am unable to get the perfect run even after changing the values back to the perfect run values.
Will update later. Thank you

**Comment by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on 2022-04-19**:
Hello, sorry for posting late as I was writing and finishing my report for this project as it is due yesterday.
I am now getting a much reliable result after changing to

```
// Turn left
if (cmdVel.angular.z > 0.4) {
  pwmLeftReq = -PWM_TURN;
  pwmRightReq = PWM_TURN;
}
// Turn right    
else if (cmdVel.angular.z < -0.4) {
  pwmLeftReq = PWM_TURN;
  pwmRightReq = -PWM_TURN;
}
```

Checked the angular value with `rostopic echo /cmd_vel` and it is 0.5 for left and -0.5 for right.
And also tried it with dwa_local_planner instead.
Thank you.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-19**:
Glad to be able to help. You can accept this answer as good enough results have been achieved. Hope you are not too frustrated with robotics and  ROS :^)

**Comment by [1024son](https://answers.ros.org/users/88308/1024son/) on 2022-04-20**:
Have accepted and ROS and robotics as a hobby is definitely going to stick with me. Not so much if its going to be a school module with risk of failing.
Thank you once again

**Comment by [Changwhan Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/132622/changwhan-lee/) on 2023-01-02**:
Hi,

I'm experiencing exactly same problem.
Original Arduino code from "Automatic Addison" of below, I think it makes robot rotate if there's any value of angular.z, it ignores linear.x.

```
  pwmLeftReq = K_P * cmdVel.linear.x + b;
  pwmRightReq = K_P * cmdVel.linear.x + b;
 
  // Check if we need to turn 
  if (cmdVel.angular.z != 0.0) {
 
    // Turn left
    if (cmdVel.angular.z > 0.0) {
      pwmLeftReq = -PWM_TURN;
      pwmRightReq = PWM_TURN;
    }
    // Turn right    
    else {
      pwmLeftReq = PWM_TURN;
      pwmRightReq = -PWM_TURN;
    }
```

}
So your workaround is making robot rotate only when angular.z is quite high.

```
// Turn left
if (cmdVel.angular.z > 0.4) {
  pwmLeftReq = -PWM_TURN;
  pwmRightReq = PWM_TURN;
}
// Turn right    
else if (cmdVel.angular.z < -0.4) {
  pwmLeftReq = PWM_TURN;
  pwmRightReq = -PWM_TURN;
}
```

I wonder you still use this workaround or better solution?

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2023-01-04**:
I will try this one for sure first - the minimal value of `cmdVel.angular.z` will probably have to be adjusted to your robot.

**Comment by [Changwhan Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/132622/changwhan-lee/) on 2023-01-05**:
Hi,

I'm trying this new code, which doesn't ignore PWM value which was calculated from linear.x.

```
vLeft = (2.0 * cmdVel.linear.x - cmdVel.angular.z * WHEEL_BASE) / 2.0 ;
vRight = (2.0 * cmdVel.linear.x + cmdVel.angular.z * WHEEL_BASE) / 2.0 ;
pwmLeftReq = K_P * vLeft + K_b;
pwmLeftReq = K_P * vLeft - K_b;
```

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2023-01-05**:
What is the result?

**Comment by [Changwhan Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/132622/changwhan-lee/) on 2023-01-05**:
Tuning is difficult, when angular.z is small, robot doesn't rotate.
So I'm working to make PID on both vLeft and VRight.

Thanks!

**Comment by [ibrahim9](https://answers.ros.org/users/163594/ibrahim9/) on 2023-07-18**:
Hi, I have the same issue. Did you find any good solution? I need to submit my FYP, just left with this issue